# Magento 2 Checkout Logs

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add Logs in Magento 2 Checkout Steps.

1. shipping Method Loading
2. Payment Methods Loading
3. Place Order

etc..

What should i use, Observers or should override the methods. Is there any plugin which can be used?

Comment: What are you trying to log?

Comment: I want to log which customer came on checkout and went till which step and n if there  was any failure on payment or shipping method loading or placing order